# Server Sent Events on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, server-sent-events

How can I achieve server sent events in WordPress. I have searched a lot about it but not able to figure out how can I implement it. The problem I am facing is SSE only takes header as `'Content-Type:text/plain'`. How can I sent some event to js script only when some changes occur in my database through WordPress function?
If I use `'Content-Type:text/plain'` in WordPress function whole website will turn into text output.

I am aware that Wordpress has heartbeat API but I don't want that. Currently, I am using ajax pooling to achieve the same task but it is taking a lot of resources.

Comment: What kind of database changes do you want to log?

Comment: I want to log few custom user metadata such as when the user has not filled certain fields I want to check it in in real time. @mdarmanin

Comment: @ShubhamMaurya: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I was able to solve it, I'll post an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a custom REST API end point and make something like that:

```
public function prepare_rest_api_demo_response( $request ){
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 1
    );
    $last_id = '';

    $serverTime = time();

    $latest_posts = get_posts( $args );
    $last_id = $latest_posts['0']->ID;

    do {
        
        $latest_posts = get_posts( $args );

        if( $latest_posts['0']->ID > $last_id ){
            $response = new WP_REST_Response($this->compile_sendMsg_in_apiendpoint_for_SSE($serverTime,$latest_posts,$last_id), 200);
            break;
        }

        // break the loop if the client aborted the connection (closed the page)

        if ( connection_aborted() ) {
            $response = new WP_REST_Response('data: {connection: "closed"}'."\n\n", 503);
            break;
        }

        sleep(2);
      
        // If we didn't use a while loop, the browser would essentially do polling
        // every ~3seconds. Using the while, we keep the connection open and only make
        // one request.
     
    } while(true);

    $response->header( 'Content-Type', 'text/event-stream' );
    $response->header( 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache' );
    //$response->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );
    $response->header( 'Accept', 'application/json' );
    return $response;
}
```

and this function for compile the response in the correct way

```
private function compile_sendMsg_in_apiendpoint_for_SSE($id, $msg, $lastitemid) {

    $msg = json_encode($msg);

    echo "id: $id" . "\n";
    echo "retry: 1500" . "\n";
    //echo "event: nameofevent" . "\n"; // if you need some name for event uncomment that line
    echo "data: $msg". PHP_EOL;//use  \n instead of PHP_EOL for add another line data: if is the same data object https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/#toc-js-api
    echo PHP_EOL;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Comment: Out of interest did this ever work? I like the idea but the headers don't change because of the echos.